# How to create object with a value from redux store

Tags: javascript, react-native, localization, react-redux

I want to create an object with specific getters and one key which is language. Based on language key getters should return different values. Its for custom language chooser option. For example, I have a getter

```
get homePage() {
   return lang === 'eng' ? "Home" : "Ui"
}
```

Object is

`export const contents = {
    lang: 'eng',
    get homePage() {
       return lang === 'eng' ? "Home" : "Ui"
    }
}`

Action

```
export const setLang = lang => ({
   type: SET_LANG,
   lang
});
```

**lang** is stored inside redux store, now I want to update object whenever it changes. Then use that objects inside other components. But I do not know how to access redux store inside object. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use selectors for redux, for example:
`const getBelts = (state) => state.items.belts`

Although your case is a little bit odd but if you really need to do it this way then you can use the `store` object that you return from `createStore` function and then use a selector function to query the store.